# Remove img class using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove the following **line** in php

```
<img class="hSprite" src="something" width="160" height="120"
sprite="/t/3010187.jpg" id="3010187">
```

I tried the following but its not working

```
preg_replace("@<img class=\"hSprite\".*?>@s", "", $html);
```

**EDIT**
I want to delete the whole line so there should be nothing  output

Comment: What is not working? What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: I want to delete everything

Comment: what do you mean by whole line??

Comment: Your regex works fine for me. What do you get? Have you any error message?

Answer (score 1):

Why not you tried dom class in php here using dom and xpath query it is able to remove the class from that img node. Don't depend on regex for dom related things use Dom classes provided by php team.

```
$text = 
<<<heredoc
        <img class="hSprite" src="something" width="160" height="120"
sprite="/t/3010187.jpg" id="3010187">
heredoc;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);

//$img = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img")->item(0);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$expression = "//*[contains(@class, 'hSprite')]";
$classElements = $xpath->query($expression);

foreach ($classElements as $element) {
    //$element->attributes->getNamedItem("class")->nodeValue = '';
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
}

//echo $doc->saveHTML($img);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Read the question more carefully, the goal is to remove all the tag, not to set the class attribute to an empty string.

Comment: Yes the whole img node.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Changed after your valuable advice thanks once again. Also maintained the old code by commenting. For relate to discussion between us.

Answer (score 1):

yuo can use this simple regex:

```
/<img.*?class="hSprite".*?>/
```

i.e.:

```
<?php

$html = <<< LOL
 <div class="refsect1 description" id="refsect1-reserved.variables.server-description">
  <h3 class="title">Description</h3>
  <p class="para">
   <var class="varname"><var class="varname">test</var></var> is an array containing information
   such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this
   array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that
   every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some,
   or provide others not listed here. That said, a large number of
   these variables are accounted for in the <a href="http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875" class="link external">test 9999</a>, so you should
   be able to expect those.
  </p>
<img class="hSprite" src="something" width="160" height="120"
sprite="/t/3010187.jpg" id="3010187">
LOL;

$newHtml = preg_replace('/<img.*?class="hSprite".*?>/sim', '', $html);

echo  $newHtml;
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/K1bJUs

Comment: this works, but in the event where there are 2 images with a class of hSprite this regex captures everything in between the 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only select the class. This should do it for you:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\<img)( ?class="[\w]+")/', '', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo str_replace("hSprite","",$html);
?>
```

You can use php function for replace this class.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace() to remove img tag from string

```
<?php

$html='nothing<img class="hSprite" src="something" width="160" height="120"
sprite="/t/3010187.jpg" id="3010187">';

$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $html); 
echo $content;
```

Comment: This will remove ALL `<img ` tags.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. He want to remove lines with `class="hSprite"`, not the other ones.

Comment: @Toto he edited his question as he say "EDIT I want to delete the whole line so there should be nothing output"

Comment: The whole line is not ALL the lines!!